# Pagination not taking effect on webpage

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I'm applying pagination on my sports.html page. In views.py I'm using `ListView` and using `paginate_by = 2` but issue is pagination is not taking effect on webpage.
Pagination numbers are visible on page and when clicking on those page numbers it's not showing any error but all posts are visible on all pages, posts are not divided by paginate_by value.
Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong here ?

**views.py**

```
class SportsList(ListView):
    model = Sports
    template_name = 'frontend/sports.html'
    paginate_by = 2

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['main'] = Main.objects.all()
        context['sports'] = Sports.objects.all()
        return context
```

**sports.html**

```
<section class="blog_area">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-8">
                    <div class="blog_left_sidebar">
                        {% for sport in sports %}
                        <article class="row blog_item">
                            <div class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="blog_info text-right">
                                    <ul class="blog_meta list">
                                        <li><a href="#">XAR<i class="lnr lnr-user"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">From: {{ sport.from_date }}<i class="lnr lnr-calendar-full"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">To: {{ sport.to_date }}<i class="lnr lnr-calendar-full"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">{{ sport.category }}<i class="lnr lnr-layers"></i></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-9">
                                <div class="blog_post">
                                    <img src="{{ sport.featured_image.url }}" alt="">
                                    <div class="blog_details">
                                        <a href="{% url 'sports_details' sport.slug %}">
                                            <h2>{{ sport.title }}</h2>
                                        </a>
                                        <p>{{ sport.content|truncatewords:30|safe }}</p>
                                        <a href="{% url 'sports_details' sport.slug %}" class="blog_btn">View More</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% if is_paginated %}
                        <nav class="blog-pagination justify-content-center d-flex">
                            <ul class="pagination">
                            {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
                                <li class="page-item">
                                    <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}" class="page-link">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">
                                            <span class="lnr lnr-chevron-left"></span>
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            {% endif %}
                            {% for num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
                                {% if page_obj.number == num %}
                                    <li class="page-item active"><a href="#" class="page-link">{{ num }}</a></li>
                                {% elif num > page_obj.number|add:'-3' and num < page_obj.number|add:'3' %}
                                    <li class="page-item"><a href="?page={{ num }}" class="page-link">{{ num }}</a></li>
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}
                            {% if page_obj.has_next %}
                                <li class="page-item">
                                    <a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}" class="page-link" aria-label="Next">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">
                                            <span class="lnr lnr-chevron-right"></span>
                                        </span>
                                    </a>
 
                                </li>
                            {% endif %}
                            </ul>
                            {% endif %}
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
              </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are creating your queryset on get_context_data. You are not respecting the listview structure. Try something like this on your view:

```
class SportsList(ListView):
    queryset = Sport.objects.all()
    context_object_name = “sports”
    template_name = 'frontend/sports.html'
    paginate_by = 2
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['main'] = Main.objects.all()
        return context
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the following in the views.py.

```
 context_object_name = 'sports'
```

By default, While a Django view is executing, `self.object_list` will contain the list of objects (usually, but not necessarily a queryset) that the view is operating upon. You can see the reference in Django doc here.
[generic list view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.list.ListView)

Of course, you are adding 'sports' in the context of `def get_context_data` but a Django generic list view need to get operated upon the value mentioned in  `context_object_name` or the `object_list`.

Hence in your views.py use:

```
class SportsList(ListView):
    model = Sports
    template_name = 'frontend/sports.html'
    paginate_by = 2
    context_object_name = 'sports'
    ordering = ["id"]
```